# Cleaning tape for automatic part cleaning during manufacturing

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, production-technology

Is there something like a consumable cleaning tape for automatically cleaning parts during manufacturing? Some parts need to be cleaned before automatic assembly, e.g. magnets before adhesive being applied to one of their surfaces. Tape may be soaked in cleaning agent like isopropyl alcohol. I'm looking for something ready to use, before trying to make it on my own.

[image]

Comment: Used to be cassette player cleaning tapes - check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen a cleaning system like this; but it may exist. It may have some merits for having good control and very high purity cleaning; but probably overly complicated for just an adhesive bonding application. Usually manufacturing tries to avoid batch operations when possible to avoid down time. Industry also avoids things that are disposable or have to be batch reconditioned to avoid the additional cost.

A simpler system for your application may be to just use compressed air and a nozzle angled to the surface. Biggest benefit here is that the nozzle does not have to be lined up perfectly with the part geometry to operate correctly. If there is contamination like oil on the surface that air alone will not remove, you could add some soapy water or alcohol via venturi into the cleaning air stream. Alcohol will work great, but soapy water is probably safer for personnel (no chemical exposure or fire risk) and doesn't have volatile organic compound VOC environmental restrictions. This system can also be combined with a vacuum system to minimize contamination released outside of the cleaning machine.

If your application does require the precision of a tape like system, maybe consider a spinning disk cleaner that could be self cleaned between each part. Similar functionality, but mechanically simpler and no disposal/reconditioning of the cleaning tape.